# Not able to automate iOS Hybrid mobile app using protractor

Tags: ios, iphone, protractor, appium

I am trying to automate an hybrid ios app using Appium and Protractor. I have installed appium 1.3.4 and xcode 6.1. While ruuning the protractor scripts displays error below. Kindly help. I have Enable UIAutomation from iPhone Developer option. Appium Logs ::

```
        info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.4 (REV c8c79a85fbd6870cd6fc3d66d038a115ebe22efe)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/qualcomm/Desktop/bhawani/AbbVieCareCH.app","ipa":"/Users/qualcomm/Desktop/bhawani/abbvieCH-dev-01.01.21050131.01.ipa","udid":"cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"iOS","appium-version":"1.3.4","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":8.1,"deviceName":"iPhone6","autoWebview":true,"count":1}}
info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : appium-version, count
info: [debug] Using local app from command line: /Users/qualcomm/Desktop/bhawani/AbbVieCareCH.app
info: [debug] Creating new appium session ca2a0eb0-f7cf-47f6-b960-93f447bb3010
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1
info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings
info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app
info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. D...ot manually modify!
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone6","platformVersion":8.1}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone6 (8.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966 --bundle com.qcl.qualcomm.healthycircles.dev
info: [debug] App is installed.
info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966  -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-02 18:05:17.723 instruments[12882:123318] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com...'
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966  -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-02 18:05:25.309 instruments[12885:123423] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com...'
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966  -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-02 18:05:31.499 instruments[12888:123447] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.qcl.qualcomm.healthycircles.dev'
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w cbecb05c855c13d9b2e6b693999123268fc0b966  -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/qualcomm/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d0f21a5b61bb08af.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-03-02 18:05:37.696 instruments[12891:123507] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com...'
info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:387:31)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 25043.363 ms - 182
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have the same problem..... Does it deploy your application to device properly? Can you run it manually, not from Appium?

Comment: Yes, I was able to deply and run the app properly manually...Issue is with appium for automation...

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing same problem